# How can I read a range('A5:B10') and place these values into a dataframe using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl

Being able to define the ranges in a manner similar to excel, i.e. 'A5:B10' is important to what I need so reading the entire sheet to a dataframe isn't very useful.

So what I need to do is read the values from multiple ranges in the Excel sheet to multiple different dataframes.

```
valuerange1 = ['a5:b10']
valuerange2 = ['z10:z20']
df = pd.DataFrame(values from valuerange)
df = pd.DataFrame(values from valuerange1)
```

or

```
df = pd.DataFrame(values from ['A5:B10'])
```

I have searched but either I have done a very poor job of searching or everyone else has gotten around this problem but I really can't.

Thanks.

Comment: So to clarify, what you want to achieve is loading *part of an excel sheet* in an pandas DataFrame? Or do you need to select parts of your data frame in that excel-like syntax?

Comment: i just edited the post. hopefully that answers your question but to clarify, I need to load parts of the excel sheet into different dataframes.

Comment: Judging by your comment, do I understand you correctly, that it is not an option to load the full excel file into memory?

Comment: i can use openpyxl.load_workbook if this is what you are referring to. I am currently loading the entire worksheet using panads.read_excel. I then define multiple ranges of this dataframe as the values of the data that I need. This is cumbersome because I need to manually figure out what rows and columns I need but that isn't the biggest problem however. I am attempting to make this script very user friendly which means excepting excel ranges rather than using iloc.

Comment: I made an edit to my answer which shows a very user-friendly solution using openpyxl.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Using openpyxl

Since you have indicated, that you are looking into a very user friendly way to specify the range (like the excel-syntax) and as Charlie Clark already suggested, you can use openpyxl.

The following utility function takes a workbook and a column/row range and returns a pandas DataFrame:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_interval
import re

def load_workbook_range(range_string, ws):
    col_start, col_end = re.findall("[A-Z]+", range_string)

    data_rows = []
    for row in ws[range_string]:
        data_rows.append([cell.value for cell in row])

    return pd.DataFrame(data_rows, columns=get_column_interval(col_start, col_end))
```

**Usage:**

```
wb = load_workbook(filename='excel-sheet.xlsx', 
                   read_only=True)
ws = wb.active
load_workbook_range('B1:C2', ws)
```

Output:

```
   B  C
0  5  6
1  8  9
```

---

## Pandas only Solution

Given the following data in an excel sheet:

```
    A   B   C
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
2   7   8   9
3  10  11  12
```

You can load it with the following command:
`pd.read_excel('excel-sheet.xlsx')`

If you were to limit the data being read, the [pandas.read_excel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) method offers a number of options. Use the `parse_cols`, `skiprows` and `skip_footer` to select the specific subset that you want to load:

```
pd.read_excel(
    'excel-sheet.xlsx',    # name of excel sheet
    names=['B','C'],       # new column header
    skiprows=range(0,1),   # list of rows you want to omit at the beginning
    skip_footer=1,         # number of rows you want to skip at the end
    parse_cols='B:C'       # columns to parse (note the excel-like syntax)
)
```

Output:

```
   B  C
0  5  6
1  8  9
```

**Some notes:**

The API of the read_excel method is not meant to support more complex selections. In case you require a complex filter it is much easier (and cleaner) to load the whole data into a DataFrame and use the excellent slicing and indexing mechanisms [provided by pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html).

Comment: the read_excel method is what I am currently using but what that required me to do was to manually select 8 different ranges by their column number and row numbers. While this is fine for me, I am trying to make this current script much more user friendly which would mean that I need to use ranges in the format given 'A5:c10' so that other users can more easily change this range. I appreciate your suggestion though

Comment: There is no need for an extra function with a regex: `ws['A1:B5']` works just fine.

Comment: Good remark. However, is there an option to get the columns for the pandas DataFrame? I'm using it as the columns array in the pd.DataFrame call

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try it but I wanted to say thank you. Seems like a perfect solution. Thanks for the response. Very much appreciated.

Comment: @CharlieClark I have edited my answer accordingly. If the column headers are included in the data itself, one could also get rid of the regex. But since the range refers to the excel column names, they need to be restored after slicing when creating the data frame.

Comment: @ChrisThomas thank you. Make sure that you accept the answer in case it works for you.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The most easiest way is to use pandas for getting the range of values from excel.

```py
import pandas as pd

#if you want to choose single range, you can use the below method
src=pd.read_excel(r'August.xlsx',usecols='A:C',sheet_name='S')

#if you have multirange, which means a dataframe with A:S and as well some other range
src=pd.read_excel(r'August.xlsx',usecols='A:C,G:I',sheet_name='S')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use particular range, for example "B3:E5", you can use the following structure.

```
src=pd.read_excel(r'August.xlsx',usecols='B:E',sheet_name='S',header=2)[0:2]
```